# Variable as default value in form dropdown?

Tags: php, html, forms, drop-down-menu, selected

I have a parser which extracts information into array $item. From my database, I am pulling all results where I store "Types" into array $getFormats.

I am then displaying $item into a big form which the user can modify (to fix any errors from the parser). In partiular, I am forcusing on $item[3] which contains "types" extracted by the parser.

My form displays $item[3] next to my dropdown list containing possible "types" contained in the database. The goal here is to allow the user to match or change the "type" the parser finds with a "type" contained in the database.

Obviously, I want the default dropdown value to be a value which matches one already in the database. If there is no match, then the default would be blank for the user to choose an appropriate type himself.

The code below demonstrates what I have. Obviously, I am going about it wrong as it doesn't work.

```
<form>
    <?php
    foreach($articles as $item) {
     ?>

     Type: <input type="text" name="typeparsed" value="<?php echo $item[3]; ?>">
           <select name="typechoose" value="<?php echo $value; ?>">
                <?php 
                        foreach ($getFormats as $format) {
                            $selected = '';
                            if($item[3] == 'entry form' && $format->name == 'Entry Form'){ 
                                $selected = 'selected';
                            }
                            echo "<option value='".$format->name."' ".$selected.">".$format->name."</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
           </select>
    <?php }?>
</form>
```

$item[3] is the array containing "type" extracted by the parser.

$format->name is the array containing the dropdown options pulled from the database.

The above code works but my problem is that $format->name contains two instances of the same value.

My database has the following "types":

```
Entry Form
Facebook
Entry Form
```

This is because of the way wordpress stores hierarchical options. On my site, these values are actually as follows:

```
Entry Form
Facebook
  - Entry Form
```

As you can see, it is because Entry Form is a top menu item AND a submenu of Facebook.

So, as I am trying to match a type of entry form with Entry Form, I run into a problem when trying to determine WHICH Entry Form is the right one to select.

As my code is presently, the second instance of Entry Form is selected.

How can I adapt the code so that if $item[3] == 'entry form' (as it is currently), then the FIRST Entry Form will be selected?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selected Entry in a Drop Down Select HTML Form Element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260627/selected-entry-in-a-drop-down-select-html-form-element)

Comment: if ($item[3] == 'entry form') { $value = 'entry form'; } else { $value = $item[3]; } will always set $value to 'entry form'

Answer (score 1):

First thing is I don't understend why You use this:

```
<?php
foreach($articles as $item) {
    if ($item[3] == 'entry form') {
        $value = 'entry form';
    } else {
        $value = $item[3];
    }
 ?>
```

You can simply use the code brlowe and it will do exacly the same:

```
<?php
foreach($articles as $item) {
   $value = $item[3];
 ?>
```

To match selected element do that:

```
Type: <input type="text" name="typeparsed" value="<?php echo $item[3]; ?>">
       <select name="typechoose" value="<?php echo $value; ?>">
          <?php 
           foreach ($getFormats as $format) {
               $selected = '';
               if($value == $format->name){ $selected = ' selected="selected" '; }
               echo "<option value='".$format->name."' ."$selected".>".$format->name."</option>";
           }
          ?>
       </select>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: The reason is because the if statement would expand and check to see if $item[3} equals other values and do different things depending on such. Obviously, I won't expand it until it works.

Comment: Ach, OK then. Have You check the oder code? It sholud give You a solution for Your problem.

Comment: It doesn't work. The reason being that $format->name contains Entry Form not entry form. The code breaks me entire form, shuffling fields all over the place.

Comment: so why don't use PHP `strtolower()` `if($value ==strtolower( $format->name) )`

Comment: Your solution proved correct but now I need to solve modified question.

Answer (score 0):

Becous You have change Your question I will put another answer witch is simple: You will not determine that as long as both "Entry Form's" have the same name. If You can check them for they database ID's please try to use it, if not then You should change their names.

```
<?php // $value is actualy ID of the element; ?>
Type: <input type="text" name="typeparsed" value="<?php echo $item[3]; ?>">
   <select name="typechoose" value="<?php echo $value; ?>">
      <?php 
       foreach ($getFormats as $format) {
           $selected = '';
           if($value == $format->id){ $selected = ' selected="selected" '; }
           echo "<option value='".$format->id."' ."$selected".>".$format->name."</option>";
       }
      ?>
   </select>
```

And as value pass ID of the selected element.

Comment: That's my problem. Since my database is from wordpress, I am limited by how wordpress implements its information. As such, the ID are numbers and since I am using a parser, which contains a string of text, I cannot match them. Furthermore, the user can modify the name of the type while the ID remains the same so trying to match by ID won't work. I must match using $format->name.

Comment: So maybe You will add Your own tabel where You will store the anmes and ID's that You will compare with those selected by User. As You said You cannot delay on the name's becouse strings can be changed easily.

Comment: What I mean is, I would rather rely on the name than on the ID because if the user changes the name, then the dropdown will not have a default value (unless the user readds the name), which is fine. But if I rely on the ID, and the user changes the name, then my form will default to an incorrect name (the changed name) rather than find the correct name (if it is readded as a new ID).